# RequestDelegate function()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am writing a microservice using the technique from here:
https://www.strathweb.com/2017/01/building-microservices-with-asp-net-core-without-mvc/

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to have the code in the RequestDelegate(s) in functions since the code here is in lambdas?

```
app.UseRouter(r =>
{
    var contactRepo = new InMemoryContactRepository();

    r.MapGet("contacts", async (request, response, routeData) =>
    {
        var contacts = await contactRepo.GetAll();
        await response.WriteJson(contacts);
    });

    r.MapGet("contacts/{id:int}", async (request, response, routeData) =>
    {
        var contact = await contactRepo.Get(Convert.ToInt32(routeData.Values["id"]));
        await response.WriteJson(contact);
    });

    r.MapGet("contacts/delete/{id:int}", async (request, response, routeData) =>
    {
        await contactRepo.Delete(Convert.ToInt32(routeData.Values["id"]));
        var contacts = await contactRepo.GetAll();
        await response.WriteJson(contacts);
    });
});
```

I'm asking because we already have some units that we need to incorporate code from into the new calls. The above is only examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would look like this:

```
app.UseRouter(r =>
{
    var contactRepo = new InMemoryContactRepository();

    r.MapGet("contacts", GetContacts);

    r.MapGet("contacts/{id:int}", GetContact);

    r.MapGet("contacts/delete/{id:int}", DeleteContact);
});
```

...

```
private async Task GetContacts(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, RouteData routeData)
{
    var contact = await contactRepo.Get(Convert.ToInt32(routeData.Values["id"]));
    await response.WriteJson(contact);
}

private async Task GetContact(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, RouteData routeData)
{
    var contact = await contactRepo.Get(Convert.ToInt32(routeData.Values["id"]));
    await response.WriteJson(contact);
}

private async Task DeleteContact(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, RouteData routeData)
{
    await contactRepo.Delete(Convert.ToInt32(routeData.Values["id"]));
    var contacts = await contactRepo.GetAll();
    await response.WriteJson(contacts);
}
```